# Importing DEM into Microstation

Tags: dem, usgs, microstation

Using QGIS version 3.28.2-Firenze.  I have a DEM obtained from USGS (EPSG:2927 - NAD83(HARN) / Washington South (ftUS)) which aligns correctly horizontally and vertically when I overlay on top of OSM in QGIS.  Problem is when I try to import as a terrain model into Microstation (Power InRoads).  When importing into Microstation, I assign the correct source and target CRS (EPSG:2927) to insert the DEM, but after importing into Microstation, Microstation displays the elevation as 3.28x larger than it should be.  I checked to ensure source and target elevation = feet during the import.  Could there be a default setting in QGIS for elevation = meters that is making the original DEM obtained from USGS in meters vice feet?

Comment: Please post a link to your data.

Comment: I've never posted a link to data, is there a specific place to post this?  I only have the DEM to post, I can't post the Microstation file.

Comment: A link to the original data, or if you've cropped the DEM you can post a link to the data using WeTransfer or DropBox.

Comment: Understood.  Here is a link to the DEM that I downloaded.  X, Y, and Z align correctly in QGIS, but when I export out of QGIS as a tif and try to import into Microstation, the Z elevation is great by 3.28.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/zavitvgtqpqofvo/USGS_OPR_WA_Western_WA_QL1_LiDAR_2016_B16_q47123a11bh.tif?dl=0

Comment: Was just thinking, I'm going to try to upload directly to Microstation from the USGS site without going through QGIS for merging.  I think something is happening in QGIS with the merge or resampling that is causing the Z elevation to be read as meters instead of feet.

Comment: When I drag-n-dropped your Tiff into QGIS it said "Unknown CRS". I re-saved with EPSG:2927 and still got the same range of elevations: 1.52 to 1073.33 Feet. I don't have Microstation to test, but I'm guessing that's where the problem is. The Tiff imports correctly into Civil 3D.

Comment: Yes, I got the tiff to import into Civil3D correctly.  It must have something to do w/ the import into Microstation, but I'm not sure why it thinks the DEM import is in meters.  Must be something in my microstation settings.